# Input Validation in Xamarin form

Tags: validation, xamarin.forms

Im currently working with xamarin form and Im beginner in this technology.
My problem is how to put some validation in my input fields. I watched videos on youtube about Xamarin community toolkit,its pretty good and cool, I can use some property later on, I cant find any solution on that video.

My expected output is; Let's say I have registration page, with 10 input fields, (e.g. Firstname(FN), Lastname(LN)). Assume I wont put any data in FN, and the rest 9 field is filled with datas so I cant click the "register" button cause the FN dont have any data.
Any link related to my post will be appreciated. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine whether FN is null or empty. If it is null or empty, set the isenable to false.

You can try the code below

```
private void myEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Entry fnentry = sender as Entry;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fnentry.Text)){
            Register.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Register.IsEnabled = true;
        }

    }

 

<Entry x:Name="FirstName" TextChanged="myEntry_TextChanged"></Entry>

<Button x:Name="Register" Text="Register" IsEnabled="False"></Button>
```

Comment: so sir I will repeat that code in my 11 input fields?

Comment: You could add "TextChanged=”myEntry_TextChanged" for each Entry, and other unchanged. Hope it could help you.